# JS: show div on page leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I override the OnBeforeUnload dialog and replace it with my own?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own)

Is there a chance to show custom popup (div) when user leave page?
I know there are **beforeunload** event, but it only show default popup. I need an custom popup with form inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is **no**.

You will only be able to display the default popup that the browser provides. It is not possible to display a custom popup such as a `<div>` as you are requesting, because by the time it is displayed the tab or window would have already closed.

To display a default popup confirm box before the user leaves the page, you should use the following JavaScript code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    return 'Are you sure you wish to leave this page?';
};
```

Comment: It is possible to display div just before page leave using mouse tracking. But it's not easy and it's not 100% success rate. Research keyword: `exit-intent`